# How to find the statistical mode of each ID

Tags: r, dplyr

Here are the observations of two individuals of my dataset.

```
data=structure(list(id = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), trt = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), status = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L), stage = c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), spiders = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), sex = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("m", "f"), class = "factor"), 
    hepato = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), edema = c(0, 0, 0, 0.5, 
    0, 0.5), ascites = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to calculate the the statistical mode for each individual after grouping by `id`. I used this code below:

```
library(dplyr)
library(modeest)

    data%>%
      group_by(id)%>%mutate(edema2=mlv(edema))
```

And I get an error message when calculating the mode, while this method work well with other statistical parameters such as `mean`, `sd`, `min`, `max`....

Comment: What's the exact error that you got?

Comment: Sorry, it worked, But I have a warning message:  ```Warning messages:
1: Problem with `mutate()` input `edema2`.
ℹ argument 'method' is missing. Data are supposed to be continuous. 
            Default method 'shorth' is used
ℹ Input `edema2` is `print(mlv(edema))`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: id = 2. 
2: argument 'method' is missing. Data are supposed to be continuous. 
            Default method 'shorth' is used 
3: Problem with `mutate()` input `edema2`.```

Comment: And the values created seem corrects

Comment: The warning says that you didn't supply the 'method' argument, so it has defaulted to the 'shorth' method. You'll have to check the documentation from the package author to find what that means. The "data are supposed to be continuous" may imply something wrong with your input values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warnings that you are getting are suggesting two things.

1. You have not specified what `method` to choose so default method 'shorth' is used.
2. It is suggesting that there is a tie in selection of Mode value.

Alternatively, why not use the `Mode` function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8189441/3962914) :

```
Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}
```

To apply by group you can use it with `dplyr` as :

```
library(dplyr)
data%>% group_by(id)%>% mutate(edema2= Mode(edema))

#     id   trt status stage spiders sex   hepato edema ascites edema2
#  <int> <int>  <int> <int>   <int> <fct>  <int> <dbl>   <int>  <dbl>
#1     2     1      0     3       1 f          1   0         0    0  
#2     2     1      0     3       1 f          1   0         0    0  
#3     2     1      0     3       1 f          1   0         0    0  
#4     3     1      2     4       0 m          0   0.5       0    0.5
#5     3     1      2     4       1 m          1   0         0    0.5
#6     3     1      2     4       0 m          0   0.5       0    0.5
```